# Angular 2 & node error while refreshing geting this error Cannot GET /register

Tags: node.js, angular, express

Hi i am getting this error in Angular 2 & node error while refreshing getting this error  Cannot GET /register,

if i am moving by navigation then its working fine but i will refresh at any route then its give me above error please help

**Express code is here**

**Server.js**

```
 var express = require('express');
var port = process.env.PORT || 3021;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var path = require('path');
var cors=require('cors');
var User = require('./models/user.model');
var User = require('./models/education.model');
var dbConfig = require('./config/db');

var app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.use(cookieParser());

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(dbConfig.db, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('faild to connect with mongo DB', err);
    }
    else {
        console.log('Connection open with mongo db');
    }
})

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(path.resolve('./dist/index.html'));
});

var userRoute = require('./routes/user.route')(app);
var educationRoute = require('./routes/education.route')(app);



app.listen(port, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        console.log('Server api runing on port ', port);
    }
})
```

after refreshing geting

```
Cannot GET /register
```

please help me , thanks in advance

Comment: there is nothing about register in your code? why did you tagged angular for this? if angular please share you routing code.

Comment: its my angular route code

Comment: const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: 'thank-you', component: ThankYouComponent },
  { path: '**', component: HomeComponent },
];

Comment: if i am moving by navigation then its fine but if i will refresh then i am getting this error

Answer (score 2):

Hi finaly i got solution of this problem by adding this code in server.js after all the routes

```
app.use('/*',function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html');
});
```